# How can I avoid a sub-query?

Tags: sql, mysql

This is my table:

```
ID   KEY    VALUE
1    alpha  100
2    alpha  500
3    alpha  22
4    beta   60
5    beta   10
```

I'm trying to retrieve a list of all `KEY`-s with their *latest* values (where `ID` is in its maximum):

```
ID   KEY     VALUE
3    alpha   22
5    beta    10
```

In MySQL I'm using this query, which is not effective:

```
SELECT temp.* FROM
  (SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY id DESC) AS temp
GROUP BY key
```

Is it possible to avoid a sub-query in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an [INNER JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) to join with your max ID's.

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    t
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  ID = MAX(ID)
          FROM    t
          GROUP BY
                  key
        ) tm ON tm.ID = t.ID
```

Assuming the ID column is indexed, this is likely as fast as its going to get.

Comment: MySQL will create **many** temporary tables, while in my example there will be only one. Are you sure that your SQL is faster??

Comment: I don't have a MySQL running but it shouldn't be hard to try both versions and compare both plans to determine the most optimal solution. Using SQL Server with only 5 ID's, both solutions perform equally fast. Using 13 ID's, the LEFT JOIN solution takes 55%, the INNER JOIN solution 45%. You can expect that difference to become even more apparent when your table grows. *Note: the ID column is the primary key and there's an index on the Value column*

Answer (score 4):

here is [the mysql documentation page that discusses this topic](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html).

it presents three distinct options.

the only one that doesn't involve a sub query is:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.k, t1.value
FROM t t1
LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t1.k = t2.k AND t1.id < t2.id
WHERE t2.k IS NULL;
```

Comment: Oops, this query is 10x times slower than my original one (there are 2mln rows in my table)...

Comment: :-)  the original question was "how to avoid a sub query"... not "how to make the most efficient query".  I believe that the choice of which query to use for optimal performance comes down to how many rows you have in your table, and how many unique values of `key`.  Glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake, I didn't specify the question properly. Thanks for your help, I up-voted your answer

Answer (score 0):

There's [page in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) explaining how to do this