# Equivalent to Max() in join query WHERE

Tags: mysql, max

I want to be able to write `ORDER BY revision_id DESC LIMIT 1` similar to `Having Max(revision_id)`, though that does not behave as I want putting it near the `WHERE` clause. Putting `Max(revision_id)` in the select, returns the highest value of the revision ID, but the rest of the fields are not the ones that ought to go with it (it's a in a join).

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM field_data_field_city
LEFT JOIN profile on(field_data_field_city.entity_id = profile.pid)
LEFT JOIN users on(profile.uid = users.uid)
WHERE users.uid = 1 
ORDER BY revision_id DESC
LIMIT 1`
```

Want to get rid of the limit so I can do it for multiple users at once

I tried with

```
GROUP BY users.uid
ORDER BY revision_id DESC
```

But I get the lowest `revision_id` and I want the highest

Comment: Can you post your table structure? It's likely that you need to group your max(revision_id) by some other fields.

Comment: You are trying to explain the result you want using SQL - but obviously the queries you are using are not returning the result you want - reading between the lines, you seem to be wanting to find the records where a maximum occurs - if this is the case then it's not only been asked and answered lots of times before, there a whole chapter in the manual on how to achive this (google mysql groupwise maximum)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I avoid a sub-query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021225/how-can-i-avoid-a-sub-query)

Answer (score 0):

You could try below:

```
WHERE revision_id=(SELECT MAX(revision_id) FROM table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the field revision_id is in your table profile you can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM field_data_field_city
LEFT JOIN profile ON field_data_field_city.entity_id = profile.pid
LEFT JOIN users ON profile.uid = users.uid
WHERE profile.revision_id IN (
    SELECT MAX(p.revision_id)
    FROM profile p
    GROUP BY p.uid) T;
```